# Selenium Webdriver - disabling browser cookie

Tags: cookies, selenium-webdriver

I need to disable the browser cookies in firefox.

I am using selenium - webdriver 2.32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve this, you'll have to first tweak profile preferences. Do following:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['network.cookie.cookieBehavior'] = 2 # disables all kind of cookies

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
```

When you open Tools -> Options -> Privacy of the browser(which is opened by driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile), you'll see picture like following which makes sure that cookie has been disabled:

[image: cookie disabled]

Comment: This does work, but the code example has a typo and stackoverflow won't let me fix it (fewer than 6 character edits prohibited, dumb rule). Change network.cookie.cookieBehvior to network.cookie.cookieBehavior