# Disable Cookies in PhantomJS driven by Selenium

Tags: cookies, selenium, phantomjs

In [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.7.html), it is possible to disable cookies using the following line:

```
phantom.cookiesEnabled = false;
```

How can I do this when PhantomJS is driven by Selenium? See: [how to disable cookies using webdriver for Chrome and FireFox JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106588/how-to-disable-cookies-using-webdriver-for-chrome-and-firefox-java) and [Selenium Webdriver - disabling browser cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849720/selenium-webdriver-disabling-browser-cookie) for how to disable cookies in Chrome and Firefox when driven by Selenium.

I am personally using the bindings from Python, but it shouldn't be a problem if the answer is posted in any other language with Selenium bindings.

Comment: Well I have the opposite issue, cookies seem disabled when I drive phantomjs from selenium. If I go on amazon.com and print the page cookies (with `document.cookie`), all I get back is `{ status: 0,
  sessionId: 'd13a2f0b-7623-4abc-9ea5-a7203a23eeab',
  value: null,
  state: null,
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  hCode: 27284725 }`.
For info, I'm using https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs.